# Algorithm Sorting list

Tags: node.js, typescript, algorithm, sorting, math

I want to write an algorithm that follows some specifics rules in node js. It takes as parameter a series of numbers and as a second the maximum consecutive (consecutive does not meant consecutive in the value but in the place in the list) number before resting and which follows this logic:

The rules :
`There is only one competition per day`
`The competitions are consecutive`
`Not all competitions bring in the same amount`
`There are N consecutive competitions`
`Contests always start on the 1st`

The programs need to display the maximum gains :

**Example:**

There are 10 numbers in the list

The consecutive number is 4

The possible outcomes are 14, 3, 14, 18, 20, 34, 1, 1, 1, 1.

The good result: **1** > **3** > **4** > **5** > **6** > **8** > **9** > **10**

Take into account that for example on this list:
[5, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3] with a maximum number of 2 I wish to do 5 > 4 > rest > 1 > rest > 2 > 3
or on this one :
[5, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3] numberConsecutives: 2 I want to do 5 > 4 > rest > rest > 2 > 3.
To maximize the gain. If somebody could help it would be wonderfull, Thanks in Advance.

I'm developing in Typescript and running my scripts with `ts-node`.

```js
function getMaxGains(numbers: any, maxConsecutiveDays: any) {
  function calculatePossibilitySum(possibility: any) {
    return possibility.reduce((acc: any, num: any) => acc + num, 0);
  }

  function generatePossibilities(numbers: any) {
    const possibilities = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= numbers.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j <= numbers.length - i; j++) {
        const possibility = numbers.slice(j, j + i);
        possibilities.push(possibility);
      }
    }

    return possibilities;
  }

  function sortPossibilities(possibilities: any) {
    return possibilities.sort(
      (a: any, b: any) =>
        calculatePossibilitySum(b) - calculatePossibilitySum(a)
    );
  }

  function findMaxGains(possibilities: any, maxConsecutiveDays: any) {
    let maxGains = 0;
    const selectedDays = new Set();

    for (const possibility of possibilities) {
      let consecutiveCount = 0;
      let canPlay = true;

      for (const day of possibility) {
        if (selectedDays.has(day)) {
          consecutiveCount = 0;
          canPlay = false;
          break;
        }
        console.log("day", day);
        consecutiveCount++;
        if (consecutiveCount > maxConsecutiveDays) {
          canPlay = false;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (canPlay) {
        console.log("possibility", possibility);
        maxGains += calculatePossibilitySum(possibility);
        possibility.forEach((day: any) => selectedDays.add(day));
      }
    }

    return maxGains;
  }
  const possibilities = generatePossibilities(numbers);
  const finalPossibilities: any = [];
  possibilities.forEach((possibilitie: any) => {
    if (possibilitie.length < maxConsecutiveDays + 1) {
      //possibilities.splice(possibilities.indexOf(possibilitie), 1);
      finalPossibilities.push(possibilitie);
    }
  });
  //console.log("possibilities", finalPossibilities);
  const sortedPossibilities = sortPossibilities(finalPossibilities);
  const maxGains = findMaxGains(sortedPossibilities, maxConsecutiveDays);

  return maxGains;
}

const example1 = [13, 12, 11, 9, 16, 17, 100];
const maxConsecutiveDays1 = 3;
const result1 = getMaxGains(example1, maxConsecutiveDays1);
console.log(result1); // Output: 178 expected: 169

const example2 = [12, 14, 52, 7, 3, 1, 1, 89, 98, 100, 12, 5, 6, 8];
const maxConsecutiveDays2 = 4;
const result2 = getMaxGains(example2, maxConsecutiveDays2);
console.log(result2); // Output: 396 expected: 399
```

*EDIT*

I've tried many things to unlock the situation, but I don't think I'm going the right way, so I'm looking for solutions or some advices that could help me understand how to do that.

`[5, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3] numberConsecutives: 2` -> I want to do `5 > 4 > rest > rest > 2 > 3`.

**Why ?**

`5 > 4 > 1 > 1 > 2 > 3` is not authorized because the number max of plays that I can do without a rest day is *2*.

`5 > 4 > rest > 1 > 2 > rest` If I go like that I'm forced to take a rest day the last day, so I lose the 3 which is better than the 1.

This is why `5 > 4 > rest > rest > 2 > 3` is the best combination because it gave me `14` which is the best number I can reach by following the rules.

Comment: *"I am completely lost"* is not a good problem statement. Please describe the problem you bump into with your implementation. For which input does it fail? What have you done to debug the situation?

Comment: I really don't get the rules of this game. What is the meaning of "days" with respect to those input values? And are those days somehow limited? Why with can't I do just 4 by 4 by 4 until I reach the end of the array? What happens on a rest? Does this skip some values from the array?

Comment: Also if seems you are using different notions for your example which is confusing even more ... and it would help, if all your examples were complete, ie mentioned the selected values, why they were selected and the total gain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that typically needs a dynamic programming approach: keep track of what the best result is so far, making the distinction between the possible lengths of the current consecutive series: so for each possible length keep track of the best result so far. That means the memoization table will have `maxConsecutiveDays+1` entries, where index 0 reflects the case where a day of rest is used. Other indices reflect that the current consecutive series is as long as that index. In other words, we consider `maxConsecutiveDays+1` scenarios in parallel. At the end we can pick the best scenario.

Here is how that would look:

```js
function getMaxGains(numbers, maxConsecutiveDays) {
    const dp = Array(maxConsecutiveDays+1).fill(0);
    for (const value of numbers) {
        const max = Math.max(...dp);
        for (let i = maxConsecutiveDays; i > 0; i--) {
            dp[i] = dp[i-1] + value;
        }
        dp[0] = max;
    }
    return Math.max(...dp);
}

const tests = [
    [[13, 2, 15, 17, 19, 33, 2, 2, 2, 2], 4, 103],
    [[5, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3], 2, 15],
    [[5, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3], 2, 14],
    [[13, 12, 11, 9, 16, 17, 100], 3, 169],
    [[12, 14, 52, 7, 3, 1, 1, 89, 98, 100, 12, 5, 6, 8], 4, 399]
];

for (const [numbers, maxConsecutiveDays, expected] of tests) {
    const result = getMaxGains(numbers, maxConsecutiveDays);
    console.log("got", result, "expected", expected);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! This will help me a lot, I will try to work on this approach